# Command Prompt: pip install mod_wsgi

Tags: python, pip, windows-10, mod-wsgi

I am on Windows 10 trying to install mod_wsgi on virtualenv. I have already downloaded flask, python, VS, ... everything. Any work around? Couldn't attach the whole error bc it's too long.

```
(venv) C:\Users\cim\Desktop\api>pip install mod_wsgi
Collecting mod_wsgi
  Using cached mod_wsgi-4.7.1.tar.gz (498 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: mod-wsgi
  Building wheel for mod-wsgi (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\cim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\cim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-install-i1jx4yl7\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\cim\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\3\\pip-install-i1jx4yl7\\mod-wsgi\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\cim\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-wheel-vuv34mr5'
       cwd: C:\Users\cim\AppData\Local\Temp\3\pip-install-i1jx4yl7\mod-wsgi\
  Complete output (211 lines):
  c:\users\cim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'bugtrack_url'
    warnings.warn(msg)
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi
  copying src\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\apxs_config.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\environ.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  copying src\server\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
  copying src\server\management\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\runmodwsgi.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  copying src\server\management\commands\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\server\management\commands
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
  copying docs\_build\html\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\docs
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\__init__.py -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  copying images\snake-whiskey.jpg -> build\lib.win32-3.8\mod_wsgi\images
  running build_ext
  building 'mod_wsgi.server.mod_wsgi' extension
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src
  creating build\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src\server
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\Apache24/include -Ic:\users\cim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include -Ic:\users\cim\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.26.28801\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\cppwinrt" /Tcsrc/server\mod_wsgi.c /Fobuild\temp.win32-3.8\Release\src/server\mod_wsgi.obj
  mod_wsgi.c
```

Comment: Use a service like pastebin.com to attach the full log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the problem. Accidentally downloaded the 32bit python package instead of the 64bit. Since Apache and VS were all 64bit I encountered this error.

Answer (score 0):

I've installed `mod_wsgi` to my mac, I can explain to you my steps, maybe you can get a hint.

- I've downloaded the latest package from the [official](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/releases) site, instead of `pip`.

  The reason is I also got error using `pip`
- I extracted the file using `tar xvfz mod_wsgi-4.6.tar.gaz`. I don't know the windows equivalent
- ./configure -> make -> make install
- Final step: Add `LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so` to the /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf

I restarted my apache server `apachectl restart`.

Before I run, I made sure the `mod_wsgi` path was correct. For my `mac`: /usr/local/lib/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so